# Is there a way to get all the category slug of a woocommerce product

Tags: php, woocommerce, cpu-word, slug, jquery-isotope

I'm making a dynamic galery of products with categories using Isotope and Woocommerce on wordpress , to sort the products I use their category slug but when a product has more than one category I cant find a way to get the other category and at this point I'm not even sure if this is possible .

I've tried to get the categories instead of the slug with `$product->get_categories();` but it returns an `<a href>` with the categories in it .

```php
function gallery(){

    Print "<div class='button-group filter-button-group'>
            <button data-filter='*' >show all</button>
            <button data-filter='.music-album'>Music</button>
            <button data-filter='.movie-soundtrack'>Movies</button>
            <button data-filter='.game-soundtrack'>Games</button>
            </div>";
    Print"<div class='row'>";

    $products= new WP_Query(['post_type'=>'product']);

    if($products->have_posts()) : while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();

        $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
        $category = $single_cat->slug.' '; // IF POSSIBLE : I want here to get all the slug of the actual product on the loop

        Print"<a class='grid-item ".$category."' href='".get_the_permalink()."'>";
        Print"<div class='card grid-item".$category."'>";
            Print"<img class='card-img-top'src='".get_field('image')."'alt='' width='200' height='200'>";
            Print"<h1 class='card-body'>"; the_title(); Print"</h1>";
        Print"</div>";
        Print"</a>";


    endwhile;endif; 

    Print"</div>";

}
```

So idealy I want the $category variable to be equal to something like `category_slug1 category_slug2 category_slug3 ....` and if the product have 10 categories I want it to find them all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$slugs = array();
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
foreach ($product_cats as $product_cat){
    $slugs[] = $product_cat->slug;
}
```

This will add all slugs into slugs array. You can then use implode() to glue it to a string.